# Allowing a User to 'equip' an owned role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am having trouble creating a command for my discord js bot. I'm looking to allow users to equip a role that they've bought. For instance, if a user has an orange role and a red role in their inventory with the orange role currently equipped, and they want to switch to the red role, I'd like for this command to check if the user *has* the red role in their inventory, and if they do, replace the orange role with the red as their highest role. The code I have currently does equip the role that is asked for, but doesn't check if the user has that role, or remove the highest role. I'm unsure as how to do that, any help is great, thank you! (The database is quick.db)

Code:

```
    let user = message.author;
    let items = await db.fetch(message.author.id);
    let author = db.fetch(`items_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)

    if (args[0] == 'tan') {
   // if author has 'tan' role in inventory; equip this role, remove the current highest role  
    await message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('813153522760679444')
    message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.subtract(highest)
    } //if not, send error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MemberRoles#has` to check if a member has a certain role. You will need to use `message.member` for this.

```
let user = message.author;

// Same as let member = message.member
let { member }  = message;

if (member.roles.cache.has('ROLE-ID-HERE')){
   // Code for member has the role
} else {
  // Code for member DOES NOT have the role
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, and does this check the database to see if the user has the role? Or just checks if the user has the role currently assigned to them? Sorry if it's a stupid question I'm quite new to this haha

Comment: This directly checks the information of the Discord Member and returns `true` if they have the role assigned to them, false otherwise.

Comment: Gotcha, I should be able to check quick.db's documentation and work from there, thank you

Comment: If my answer solved your issue click the checkmark near the votes count to help those with the same issue in the future!